# Run 2 MySQL update queries in one PHP file

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I try to run

```
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername,$username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
$sql = "UPDATE pm_videos SET `description` = REPLACE(  `description` ,'Facebook',  '')";
$sql = "UPDATE pm_videos SET `description` = REPLACE(  `description` ,'Twitter',  '')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
echo "Record updated successfully";
} else {
echo "Error updating record: " .  $conn->error;
}
$conn->close();
```

but only Twitter will be replaced. I'm new in PHP. Maybe someone could help me to fix this. Thank you.

Comment: you are reassigning the variable `$sql` variable when you do `$sql = ...` the second time. This has nothing to do with php or mysql, this is how variable assignment functions in most scripting languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$conn->query($sql)` statement runs your query. You are overwriting the first `$sql` (the one with Facebook) before you run it. You'll wan to do something like

```
$sql = "UPDATE pm_videos SET `description` = REPLACE(  `description` ,'Facebook',  '')";
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Record updated successfully with Facebook";
} else {
    echo "Error updating record: " .  $conn->error;
}
$sql = "UPDATE pm_videos SET `description` = REPLACE(  `description` ,'Twitter',  '')";
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Record updated successfully with Twitter";
} else {
    echo "Error updating record: " .  $conn->error;
}
```

Comment: Do you have an idea how i can fix it? remove if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE)

Comment: I edited the answer with a fix to run both queries and report the success of each. There are, of course, a number of different possibilities depending on what your requirements are.

Comment: One last question. Do you also know how I can replace a whole set or word like It’s Showtime or TFC.TV.

Answer (score 2):

Your first query won't be executed because the $sql string will be overwritten, and you end up executing only the second one.

Since you are executing the same query more than once, only changing a parameter, I would suggest you to use prepared statements and placeholders, something like this:

```
$sql = "UPDATE pm_videos SET `description` = REPLACE(`description`, ?,  '')";

$conn = new mysqli($servername,$username, $password, $dbname);
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('s', $content);

$content='facebook';
$stmt->execute();

$content='twitter';
$stmt->execute();

$stmt->close();
$conn->close();
```

(I removed all error checks, you might want to add your own error checking routine).